# SQL conditional join or where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Query

```
UPDATE ea
    SET ea.isholiday = 1
    FROM employee_attendance ea
    JOIN setup_holiday h ON h.day = DATEPART(dd,ea.timestamp) 
    AND h.month = DATEPART(mm,ea.timestamp)
WHERE ea.isactive = 1
```

I need to add other filter that is:

```
AND h.year = DATEPART(yyyy, ea.timestamp)
```

But, it not that easy, because I don't want to apply this filter if `year` = 0

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a case statement and a trick -- when you have the predicate you want to ignore you just put the right hand side (which will always be true) otherwise your predicate.  Like this:

```
UPDATE ea
    SET ea.isholiday = 1
FROM employee_attendance ea
JOIN setup_holiday h ON h.day = DATEPART(dd,ea.timestamp) 
  AND h.month = DATEPART(mm,ea.timestamp)
WHERE ea.isactive = 1
  AND (CASE WHEN h.year = 0 THEN DATEPART(yyyy, ea.timestamp)
            ELSE h.year END) = DATEPART(yyyy, ea.timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the condition using `or`:

```
UPDATE ea
    SET ea.isholiday = 1
    FROM employee_attendance ea JOIN
         setup_holiday h
         ON h.day = DATEPART(dd,ea.timestamp) AND
            h.month = DATEPART(mm,ea.timestamp) AND
            (h.year = DATEPART(yyyy, ea.timestamp) or h.year = 0)
WHERE ea.isactive = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
UPDATE ea
SET
   ea.isholiday = 1
FROM
   dbo.setup_holiday h
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 0, 9999 WHERE h.year = 0
      UNION ALL SELECT h.year, h.year WHERE h.year <> 0
   ) Y (StartYear, EndYear)
   INNER JOIN dbo.employee_attendance ea
      ON h.day = DATEPART(dd, ea.timestamp) 
      AND h.month = DATEPART(mm, ea.timestamp)
      AND h.year BETWEEN Y.StartYear AND Y.EndYear
WHERE
   ea.isactive = 1
;
```

Notes:

- Please use the schema prefix (such as `dbo.`) on tables and views. This prevents the engine from trying to find the object in more than one schema when the current user is not a database admin. I think that not doing this may also prevent using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` on your views, functions, and stored procedures, though I'm not sure at this moment.
- I prefer this sort of table-type split logic rather than complex `CASE` and other expressions. To me, the intent is much more clear, and it's easier to reason about the results. Once you get how `CROSS APPLY` works, I think using it makes things much more elegant.
- In any case, putting the `h.year` predicate in the `ON` clause is better than in the `WHERE` clause, since it's a condition for the join, and is not really about filtering.
- If you were to design this system from scratch, I would suggest actually placing the `StartYear` and `EndYear` columns into the `setup_holiday` table in place of `year`, just so that you could follow this exact pattern without the `CROSS APPLY`. This also allows you to stop using the "magic value" (sometimes called a "sentinel value") of `0` for the year--it just works, and supports year ranges, besides--a fragility of the current system that only supports specifying each and every year or no year at all.
- It's best practice to end your queries with a semicolon `;` to future-proof your code and eliminate silly usage of semicolons before CTEs. [Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in SQL Server 2014 and earlier, it will be required in a future version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx).
- While it's entirely a matter of personal preference, how can you possibly read queries efficiently when you put at the same indentation level items of different importance (lining up `FROM` with `JOIN` and `AND` which are each of different significance)? And how can you tolerate having some of your `ON` conditions at the end of the `JOIN` line, and some on the next line? In my opinion, you're hurting your ultimate maximum query-scanning speed by choosing a format that doesn't leverage indentation properly and put the same things together, with important signal words at the *beginning* of lines.

Comment: I figured the OP felt UPDATE and WHERE were the most important signal words, but I agree that the un-traditional indenting did bother me too.

Comment: @Hogan the indenting in your query bugs me to no end, too. :) My indenting scheme is hierarchical and consistent, indenting each next level of less-important information.